# Configure multiple databases in zf2 with doctrine2

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

How can I configure (and use) multiple databases in Zend Framework 2 with doctrine 2 ? Currently I have this in my local.php:

```
return array(
'doctrine' => array(
    'connection' => array(
        // default connection name
        'orm_default' => array(
            'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver',
            'params' => array(
                'host'     => 'localhost',
                'port'     => '3306',
                'user'     => 'root',
                'password' => '',
                'dbname'   => 'data1',
                'charset' => 'utf8', 
                'driverOptions' => array(
                        1002=>'SET NAMES utf8'
                )
            )
        )
    )
),
```

);

But I do not see a way to add a second one.

Comment: I read all of your posts, you don't search anything, and copy paste the code we provide for you, you better have to connect your brain and think, otherwise you'll post every single error message on stackoverflow without learning something...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this example might show you the way, this is how I configured two databases in my application, but I'm not using Doctrine.

DBs configuration

```
return array(
    'doctrine' => array(
        'connection1' => array(
            // default connection name
            'orm_default' => array(
                'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver',
                'params' => array(
                    'host'     => 'localhost',
                    'port'     => '3306',
                    'user'     => 'root',
                    'password' => '',
                    'dbname'   => 'data1',
                    'charset' => 'utf8', 
                    'driverOptions' => array(1002 => 'SET NAMES utf8')
                )
            )
        ),

        'connection2' => array(
            // default connection name
            'orm_default' => array(
                'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver',
                'params' => array(
                    'host'     => 'localhost',
                    'port'     => '3306',
                    'user'     => 'root',
                    'password' => '',
                    'dbname'   => 'data2',
                    'charset' => 'utf8', 
                    'driverOptions' => array(1002 => 'SET NAMES utf8')
                )
            )
        )
    ),
);
```

Then you need to create a DbAdapterFactory that connect to DB `connection1` and another factory to connect to DB `connection2`:

PS: Of course the names are just examples and you can use better ones.

```
class Adapter1Factory implements FactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * Create DbAdapter
     *
     * @param  ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator
     * @return DbAdapter
     */
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $config    = $serviceLocator->get('config');
        $configDb1 = $config['connection1'];
        $adapter   = new \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter($configDb1);

        return $adapter;
    }
}

class Adapter2Factory implements FactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * Create DbAdapter
     *
     * @param  ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator
     * @return DbAdapter
     */
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $config    = $serviceLocator->get('config');
        $configDb2 = $config['connection2'];
        $adapter   = new \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter($configDb2);

        return $adapter;
    }
}
```

Now just use the specific AdapterFactory when you want to connect to certain DB.

Comment: i need to use doctrine how can i do that on doctrine and how can i generate two entity for two data 1 and data 2 in same module Thanks in advance